# Live stream Lync video in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, lync

I have a requirement to publish the Live lync video conference in SharePoint 2013 Site or Embedded the meeting in sharepoint 2013 .So all the people from my organization can view the important meetings in landing page with out any invitation.Can any one help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if you thought of using the Outlook Sync features of SharePoint.

You can open a SharePoint Calendar in Outlook and then you copy / paste these meetings into the SharePoint Calendar.

This is not a programmatic solution - but this solution takes 2 seconds.

Added benefit is that anyone who opens the SharePoint Calendar in Outlook can get notifications of events and it's always sync'd

Comment: Thanks for your response.I want to display live meeting session in sharepoint site.

Comment: I have suggested an edit to this question as your original title was unclear